# junit xml assert ignoring an element

Tags: java, xml, junit

I have two XML trees and would like to compare them ignoring a specific node(s) (i.e. `<time>...</time>` in this case). How do I accomplish this with the minimal lines of code? Preferably not through XML parsing. My XMLs are typically big in size, hence they have many nodes in them.

**EDIT:** The order of nodes may or may not be the same. But if you have a solution that works with a fixed XML structure, it's also welcomed.

*Original tree:*

```
<dob>
    <day>1</day>
    <time>123456789</time>
    <month>2</month>
    <year>1980</year>
</dob>
```

---

*Compare with:*

```
<dob>
    <day>1</day>
    <time>10000009</time>
    <month>2</month>
    <year>1980</year>
</dob>
```

Comment: If you want a decent working code, I think you *need* to use an xml parser.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno anything through XML assert libraries?

Comment: If you can somehow guarantee that the order of the elements in the nodes is fixed (maybe hacking the deserializer that generate them) you can regex replace away the field you want to ignore and then string compare. Short of that, You probably need to deserialize in a bean without that field?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia I updated my post

Comment: Have you tried something with [XMLUnit](http://www.xmlunit.org/)?

Comment: @potame I've looked at the API, is there a specific method you think would take care of this situation?

Comment: you can easily create a Diff between to xml document with xmlunit, then assert on the difference